# Android backgroud thread cannot change textview through handler

Tags: android

I am unable to understand why my background thread is not able to change the content of textView(**txtName**) after screen orientation is changed.

If I make **txtname** as static it works, but without static it does not work. It just has its initial value not getting updated by the background thread.

```
private TextView txtName;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
   // String data = i.getStringExtra("data");
    // Displaying Received data
    txtName.setText("HI");
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Binding Click event to Button
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              //Closing SecondScreen Activity
              Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                     try {
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                      Message msg = new Message();
                      Bundle b = new Bundle();
                      b.putString("My Key", "My Value: " + String.valueOf(i));
                      msg.setData(b);
                      // send message to the handler with the current message handler
                      handler.sendMessage(msg);
                      Log.e("Error", "IN THREAD");
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                     }
                    }
                   }
              });
              background.start();
        }
    });


    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
             returnIntent.putExtra("returnResult","i want to back page.");
             setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
             finish();

        }
    });



}








Handler handler = new Handler() {

      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       // get the bundle and extract data by key
       Bundle b = msg.getData();
       String key = b.getString("My Key");
       txtName.setText( "Item " + key);
       txtName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       Log.e("TEST MESSAGE",  txtName.getText().toString());
      }

     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try runOnUiThread:

```
@Override 
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){ 
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 // get the bundle and extract data by key
                 Bundle b = msg.getData();
                 String key = b.getString("My Key");
                 txtName.setText( "Item " + key);
                 txtName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 Log.e("TEST MESSAGE",  txtName.getText().toString());
             }
         });
      }
   };
}
```

Comment: I edited the example below to put your code onto onConfigurationChanged, still using runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 0):

Create your OnClickListener as a fixed Class and then apply it as:

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();

btnClose.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

In this way the `txtName` variable musn't be set as final

Answer (score 0):

Your UI can only be updated by the UI thread. Try something like this to ask your UI thread to update the interface as soon as possible. This way i think you can avoid using a handler.

```
btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              //Closing SecondScreen Activity
              Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                     try {
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                      final String val = "My Value: " + String.valueOf(i);
                      // ask UI thread to make the changes as soon as possible
                      txtName.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                              txtName.setText( "Item " + val);
                              txtName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         });
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                     }
                    }
                   }
              });
              background.start();
        }
    });
```