# onClickListener not work will thread is in run mode?

Tags: android, multithreading, button

i am trying to make kind of player, so, I setup play button and pause button and make them clickListener .  when i press play button the thread start (and it work fine) but the pause button dont work until the thread is finished. what can i do to fix it?

constructor:

```
 play = false;
 playButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
 playButton.setOnClickListener(playButtonClick);
```

the runnable:

```
private Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {      
@Override
public void run() {
    int count=0;
    long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(count<24*3 && play)
    {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis()-time>41.67){
            count++;
            time=System.currentTimeMillis();
            scene.play();
            draw(sf.getHolder());
        }
    }
    play=false;
}
```

clickListener:

```
 private OnClickListener playButtonClick=new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
               if (!play){
                      play = true           
                      scene=new TestScene(3,t);
                      thread=new Thread(runnable);
                      thread.run();
                }else
                      play = false;
    }
};
```

the problem: when the thread is run i cant stop it the function clicklistner is working just when the thread is stop.

Comment: You should show us your code (the relevant parts of it)

Comment: yea, your question is to abstract, show all your code. How do you expect anyone to help you with this tiny information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Thread.start() instead of Thread.run()

See Thread Docs:

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

**Edit:**
You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841322/1561306) answer for more information about start vs. run

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, A `Thread` is running in it's own space. The only way to halt a `Thread` is to tell it to Halt. You could set some static variable that the `Thread` is listening on. The `Thread` can take necessary action depending on the state of the variable. In the simplest scenario Pressing the pause button could change a static variable in the `Thread` class file

Comment: i tried as you can see in the code above. the problem is when the thread is run the click listener not work

Comment: Use a Handler or read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897614/android-backgroud-thread-cannot-change-textview-through-handler)